Icon decorators in eclipse
In the Eclipse Package Explorer, the bottom left of the icons mean something. What do they mean?

I tried to set compiler compliance and some disappeared, other are still there. What should I do to make them go away?
BTW, I'm using the latest version of Eclipse 2024-06R.

https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm?cp=1_4_13

Please read How to Ask. You should try the documentation before asking as part of basic research.

I actually read the manual mentioned above before I posted. This is my first post but I read this forum for a long time.

Look at the Problems view to see all the problems.

The dark theme plugin you have installed changes the decorators and patches Eclipse via loadtime weaving which can cause issues and slow down Eclipse (the vendor of this plugin tries to cheat the open source license of Eclipse by doing so). The decorators at the bottom left of the fourth and fifth projects are warning signs indicating that warnings exist in those projects. There also seem to be decorators at the bottom left of the third and last project that I do not recognize. You might consider to use a more ergonomic theme.

You say you are using the "latest version of Eclipse". Can you include what version that is in the question? This will help if someone comes across this question in the future and they are facing the same problem.
